# turn null values when update

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables. sales and produclist. some of the data existing in both table are common. so what i want to do is that i want to update selected fields in tbl productlist  where tbl prodctlist data exist in tbl sales. i used this following query below but the problem is that  if data from produclist is not existing in sales it turns to null. what i am looking for is that if data from tbl productlist does not exist in tbl sales it will not turn to null, instead stay the same for what value it has before updating

```
mysql_query("UPDATE productlist 
SET pleft=pleft+(SELECT SUM(qty) FROM sales 
WHERE (sales.name = productlist.pdesc) 
AND (sales.name1 = productlist.pdesc1))");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to used `COALESCE` which takes the first non-null value:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(qty, 0)) ...
```

Comment: same output display values that does not exist in another table turns null :(

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What happened vs what were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE productlist SET pleft=pleft + IFNULL( (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM sales WHERE (sales.name = productlist.pdesc) AND (sales.name1 = productlist.pdesc1), 0)");
```

Also, if qty field can be NULL, it is better to have:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE productlist SET pleft=pleft + IFNULL( (SELECT SUM(IFNULL(qty,0)) FROM sales WHERE (sales.name = productlist.pdesc) AND (sales.name1 = productlist.pdesc1), 0)");
```